# JavaScript flattening an array of arrays of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, flatten

I have an array which contains several arrays, each containing several objects, similar to this.

```
[[object1, object2],[object1],[object1,object2,object3]]
```

Here is a screenhot of the object logged to the console.
[image]

What would be the best approach to flattening this out so it just an array of objects?

I've tried this with no luck:

```
console.log(searchData);  
  var m = [].concat.apply([],searchData);    
console.log(m);
```

searchData logs out the screenshot above, but m logs out [ ]

Here is the actual contents of searchData:

```
[[{"_id":"55064111d06b96d974937a6f","title":"Generic Title","shortname":"generic-title","contents":"<p>The Healing Center offers practical, social, and spiritual support to individuals and families. Services include, but are not limited to: food and clothing, job skills training and job search assistance, auto repair (Saturdays only), mentoring, financial counseling, tutoring, prayer, life skills training, and helpful information about local community services.</p><p>Stay in touch with us:</p>","__v":0},{"_id":"5508e1405c621d4aad2d2969","title":"test english","shortname":"test-page","contents":"<h2>English Test</h2>","__v":0}],[{"_id":"550b336f33a326aaee84f883","shortname":"ok-url","title":"now english","contents":"<p>okokko</p>","category":"Transportation","__v":0}]]
```

Comment: i like `arr.reduce(function(a,b){return a.concat(b);});`

Comment: for some reason that gives me an empty [ ]. Several other methods I've tried also have...I'm not sure why?

Comment: you're doing something else wrong if all the options presented are not working.

Comment: can you just post the content of searchData as well ?

Comment: Works: http://jsfiddle.net/m415vttv/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: To flatten deeply nested array of objects you need recursion. Check [this post](https://www.techighness.com/post/javascript-flatten-deeply-nested-array-of-objects-into-single-level-array/) for a solution.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

You can use [*Array.concat*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) like bellow:-

```
var arr = [['object1', 'object2'],['object1'],['object1','object2','object3']];
var flattened = [].concat.apply([],arr);
```

`flattened` will be your expected array.

ES 2020 gives the [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), also [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) if you want to iterate over, to flat lists of lists:

```js
[['object1'], ['object2']].flat() // ['object1', 'object2']
```

Comment: For some reason this returns an empty array. Any ideas why that might be occuring?

Comment: i like this better even than my reduce answer.

Comment: It works on the array provided in the answer. For some reason my array returns [ ] though.

Comment: @byrdr can you post what exactly you are trying?

Comment: @Mritunjay can you please add explanation to your code?

Comment: @NishanthMatha the trick is that .apply() takes the arguments as an array see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Comment: Neither approach works for me. I use `json_files.map((json_file: File) => {
      json_file.text().then(value => a_nested_array.push(JSON.parse(value)))
    });` to create the array and wanted to do `a_nested_array.flat()` ... but the nested arrays are not flattened

Answer (score 18):

A recursive solution for deep (nested) flattening:

```js
function flatten(a) {
  return Array.isArray(a) ? [].concat.apply([], a.map(flatten)) : a;
}
```

A bit more compactly with ES6:

```
var flatten = a => Array.isArray(a) ? [].concat(...a.map(flatten)) : a;
```

For fun, using a generator named `F` for "flatten", to lazily generate flattened values:

```
function *F(a) {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) for (var e of a) yield *F(e); else yield a;
}

>> console.log(Array.from(F([1, [2], 3])));
<< [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

For those not familiar with generators the `yield *` syntax yields values from another generator. `Array.from` takes an iterator (such as results from invoking the generator function) and turns it into an array.

Answer (score 12):

If you only need simple flatten, this may works:

```
var arr = [['object1', 'object2'],['object1'],['object1','object2','object3']];
var flatenned = arr.reduce(function(a,b){ return a.concat(b) }, []);
```

For more complex flattening, Lodash has the flatten function, which maybe what you need: https://lodash.com/docs#flatten

```
//Syntax: _.flatten(array, [isDeep])

_.flatten([1, [2, 3, [4]]]);
// → [1, 2, 3, [4]];

// using `isDeep` to recursive flatten
_.flatten([1, [2, 3, [4]]], true);
// → [1, 2, 3, 4];
```

Comment: good example for showing why to prefer [].reduce vs _.flatten !

Comment: @dandavis Well, all he needs to do is specify the optional argument to `_.flatten` to get the deep behavior, or call `_.flattenDeep`.

Answer (score 6):

you can use [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) :

```js
const data = [ [{id:1}, {id:2}], [{id:3}] ];
const result = data.flat();
console.log(result);

// you can specify the depth

const data2 = [ [ [ {id:1} ], {id:2}], [{id:3}] ];
const result2 = data2.flat(2);

console.log(result2);
```

in your case  :

```js
const data = [[{"_id":"55064111d06b96d974937a6f","title":"Generic Title","shortname":"generic-title","contents":"<p>The Healing Center offers practical, social, and spiritual support to individuals and families. Services include, but are not limited to: food and clothing, job skills training and job search assistance, auto repair (Saturdays only), mentoring, financial counseling, tutoring, prayer, life skills training, and helpful information about local community services.</p><p>Stay in touch with us:</p>","__v":0},{"_id":"5508e1405c621d4aad2d2969","title":"test english","shortname":"test-page","contents":"<h2>English Test</h2>","__v":0}],[{"_id":"550b336f33a326aaee84f883","shortname":"ok-url","title":"now english","contents":"<p>okokko</p>","category":"Transportation","__v":0}]]

const result = data.flat();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 5):

> **Using ES6 Spread Operator**

`Array.prototype.concat(...searchData)`

OR

`[].concat(...searchData)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use this custom recursive method to flattened any nested array

```
const arr = [
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, [7, 8], 9],
  [10, 11, 12]
]

const flatenedArray = arr => {
  let result = [];
  if(!arr.constructor === Array) return;
  arr.forEach(a => {
    if(a.constructor === Array) return result.push(...flatenedArray(a));
    result.push(a);
  });
  return result;
}


console.log(flatenedArray(arr)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Answer (score 2):

Recursively flatten an array:

```js
function flatten(array) {
   return !Array.isArray(array) ? array : [].concat.apply([], array.map(flatten));
}
 
var yourFlattenedArray = flatten([[{"_id":"55064111d06b96d974937a6f","title":"Generic Title","shortname":"generic-title","contents":"<p>The Healing Center offers practical, social, and spiritual support to individuals and families. Services include, but are not limited to: food and clothing, job skills training and job search assistance, auto repair (Saturdays only), mentoring, financial counseling, tutoring, prayer, life skills training, and helpful information about local community services.</p><p>Stay in touch with us:</p>","__v":0},{"_id":"5508e1405c621d4aad2d2969","title":"test english","shortname":"test-page","contents":"<h2>English Test</h2>","__v":0}],[{"_id":"550b336f33a326aaee84f883","shortname":"ok-url","title":"now english","contents":"<p>okokko</p>","category":"Transportation","__v":0}]]
);

log(yourFlattenedArray);

function log(data) {
  document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) + '</pre><hr>');
}
```

```css
* {font-size: 12px; }
```

Comment: That worked! thank you, I'll have to dissect the code. So why is this one working when the others did not?

Comment: Something vaguely non-DRY about checking for array-ness twice.

Comment: @byrdr: The other answers work fine unless you misrepresented the data.

Comment: Oddly enough, I was wrong, When I replaced the array with the variable containing my array I returned [ ] again

Comment: @byrdr I'm using your own data. I don't understand.

Comment: @byrdr:  You have several solutions that have been verified as working, yet you report the same problem. This should tell you that the problem is elsewhere. Is this data coming from an XHR request? If so, are you not waiting for the response before logging the data?

Comment: @torazaburo Good eyes

Comment: @LyeFish it is odd, they do all work on the string of json, just not on the variable. The data is coming from a promise...

Comment: @byrdr is the JSON parsed? JSON.parse(data) ?

Comment: @Moogs SyntaxError: Unexpected token , Maybe that's the reason for the odd behavior

Comment: @LyeFish the variable searchData is the response data of an angular promise

Comment: @Moogs JSON.stringify returns [[],[]] ...any ideas?

Comment: @byrdr: It's not worth guessing when you could just provide actual code that you're running and with the logging you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

```
let functional = {
    flatten (array) {
        if (Array.isArray(array)) {
            return Array.prototype.concat(...array.map(this.flatten, this));
        }

        return array;
    }
};

functional.flatten([0, [1, 2], [[3, [4]]]]); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

Comment: This answer is ECMAScript 2015 which is not covered by the [tag:javascript] tag, unless the appropriate tag has been appended to the tag list of this question, a traditional JavaScript answer is expected.

Answer (score 2):

I've noticed that people are using recursions which are not cost friendly, especially with new ES6 standards giving us the power of spread operators. When you're pushing the items into the master array just use ... and it will automatically add flattened objects. Something like

```
array.push(...subarray1)    // subarray1 = [object1, object2]
array.push(...subarray2)    // subarray2 = [object3]
array.push(...subarray3)    // subarray3 = [object4,object5, object6]
// output -> array = [object1, object2, object3, object4, object5, object6]
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution to flatten an array of objects and return a single array.

```js
flattenArrayOfObject = (arr) => {
  const flattened = {};

  arr.forEach((obj) => {
    Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
      flattened[key] = obj[key];
    });
  });

  return flattened;
};
```

Example

```js
const arr = [
  {
    verify: { '0': 'xyzNot verified', '1': 'xyzVerified' },
    role_id: { '1': 'xyzMember', '2': 'xyzAdmin' },
    two_factor_authentication: { '0': 'No', '1': 'Yes' }
  },
  { status: { '0': 'xyzInactive', '1': 'Active', '2': 'xyzSuspend' } }
]

flattenArrayOfObject(arr)

// {
//   verify: { '0': 'xyzNot verified', '1': 'xyzVerified' },
//   status: { '0': 'xyzInactive', '1': 'Active', '2': 'xyzSuspend' },
//   role_id: { '1': 'xyzMember', '2': 'xyzAdmin' },
//   two_factor_authentication: { '0': 'No', '1': 'Yes' }
// }
```

Answer (score 1):

If each object has an array and continues in the same way nested :

```
function flatten(i,arrayField){
  if(Array.isArray(i)) return i.map(c=>flatten(c,arrayField));
  if(i.hasOwnProperty(arrayField)) return [{...i,[arrayField]:null},...i[arrayField].map(c=>flatten(c,arrayField))];
  return {...i,[arrayField]:null};
}

let data=flatten(myData,'childs');
```

mydata like this :

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "t1",
    "sort_order": 200,
    "childs": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "t2",
            "sort_order": 200,
            "childs": []
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title":"mytitle",
            "sort_order": 200,
            "childs": []
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title":"mytitle",
            "sort_order": 200,
            "childs": []
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "title":"mytitle",
            "sort_order": 200,
            "childs": []
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "title":"mytitle",
            "sort_order": 200,
            "childs": []
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "title": "راهنما",
    "sort_order":"mytitle",
    "childs": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "title":"mytitle",
            "sort_order": 200,
            "childs": []
        },
        {
            "id": 9,
            "title":"mytitle",
            "sort_order": 200,
            "childs": []
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "title":"mytitle",
            "sort_order": 200,
            "childs": []
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

```js
let nestedArray = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]];

let flattenArray = function(nestedArray) {

 let flattenArr = [];
  
 nestedArray.forEach(function(item) {
   flattenArr.push(...item);
  });
  
  return flattenArr;
};

console.log(flattenArray(nestedArray)); // [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [1,[9,22],[[3]]];
var res = [];

function flatten(arr){
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
if(typeof arr[i] == "number"){
res.push(arr[i]);
}
else if(typeof arr[i] == "object"){
fatten(arr[i]);
}
}
}
```

Calling function

```
flatten(arr);
console.log(res);
```

Result

```
[1, 9, 22, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// Polyfill flat method

var flatten = a => Array.isArray(a) ? [].concat(...a.map(flatten)) : a;

var deepFlatten = (arr, depth = 1) => {
   return depth > 0 ? arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(Array.isArray(val) ? deepFlatten(val, depth - 1) : val), [])
                : arr.slice();
}

console.log(deepFlatten([0, 1, 2, [[[3, 4]]]], Infinity));

// You can pass label in place of 'Infinity'
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is a way to achieve a flattened array from a multidimensional array

For two dimentional array

```js
const data = [
  [{id: 1, name: 'Test Name'}], 
  [{id: 2, name: 'Test Name 2'}]
 ].flat()
console.log(data)
```

For multidimensional array

```js
const data = [
  [{id: 1, name: 'Test Name'}], 
  [
    {id: 2, name: 'Test Name 2'}, 
    [{id: 3, name: 'Test Name 3'}]
  ]
].flat(Infinity)
console.log(data)
```