# Javascript: Print all paths in a JSON tree including arrays

Tags: javascript

Example JSON:

```
{
  name: "A",
  childNodes: [{
    name: "B",
    childProps: [{
      prop_list: [{
        name: "BS1"
      }, {
        name: "BS2"
      }]
    }],
    childNodes: [{
      name: "C",
      childProps: [{
        prop_list: [{
          name: "CS1"
        }, {
          name: "CS2"
        }]
      }],

    }]


  }],
  childProps: [{
    prop_list: [{
      name: "AS1"
    }, {
      name: "AS2"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I want to print output in the following manner.

```
    A, B, BS1
    A, B, BS2
    A, B, C, CS1
    A, B, C, CS2
    A, AS1
    A, AS2
```

Basically, I want to print the path to each leaf node. (And I need to get the name property value for each object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript flattening an array of arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158723/javascript-flattening-an-array-of-arrays-of-objects)

Comment: It's not clear what you don't include the `childProps` of `A` (`CS1` and `AS2`).

Comment: also see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: I have corrected it. AS1 and AS2 are in childProps property of A

Comment: @Lizzzz90 you first have to flatten it to an array; and then `.join(', ')` to string... traversing the structure, while building up the string would work, too.

Comment: @MartinZeitler
 flattening it or traversing it gives me o/p in this way,
{ name: 'A',
  'childNodes.0.name': 'B',
  'childNodes.0.childProps.0.prop_list.0.name': 'BS1',
  'childNodes.0.childProps.0.prop_list.1.name': 'BS2',
  'childNodes.0.childNodes.0.name': 'C',
  'childNodes.0.childNodes.0.childProps.0.prop_list.0.name': 'CS1',
  'childNodes.0.childNodes.0.childProps.0.prop_list.1.name': 'CS2',
  'childProps.0.prop_list.0.name': 'AS1',
  'childProps.0.prop_list.1.name': 'AS2' }

Can you please be more specific as to how I can collect just the values of "name" from each path?

Comment: That's not JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your problem you must loop over each item in your object and use a recursive function to append nested names to your path string.

Here is an example to get you started

```js
var obj = {
  name: "A",
  childNodes: [{
    name: "B",
    childProps: [{
      prop_list: [{
        name: "BS1"
      }, {
        name: "BS2"
      }]
    }],
    childNodes: [{
      name: "C",
      childProps: [{
        prop_list: [{
          name: "CS1"
        }, {
          name: "CS2"
        }]
      }],

    }]


  }],
  childProps: [{
    prop_list: [{
      name: "AS1"
    }, {
      name: "AS2"
    }]
  }]
};

(function findName(o, path = '') {
  const isLastLevel = !o.childProps && !o.childNodes;
  path += isLastLevel ? o.name : o.name + ', ';

  if (o.childProps) {
    o.childProps.forEach(props => {
      props.prop_list.forEach(prop => {
        findName(prop, path);
      });
    });
  }

  if (o.childNodes) {
    o.childNodes.forEach(node => {
      findName(node, path);
    });
  }

  if (isLastLevel) {
    console.log(path);
  }
})(obj);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: that's what I've meant with traversal.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could take a more generalized approach to implementing this using recusion, so that your traversal works for any format of input data:

```
function printPaths(node, path) {

  const nodeName = node.name ? (path ? ',' : '') + node.name : ''
  const nodePath = (path ? path : '') + nodeName  
  const nodeChildren = Object.values(node).filter(Array.isArray).flat()

  return nodeChildren.length > 0 ? nodeChildren
  .map(nodeChild => printPaths(nodeChild, nodePath)).flat() : nodePath
}
```

This solution is decoupled from your specific format of input data, meaning it will examine the current `node` object and traverse any array values found, eventually returning all discovered the paths:

```js
var input = {
  name: "A",
  childNodes: [{
    name: "B",
    childProps: [{
      prop_list: [{
        name: "BS1"
      }, {
        name: "BS2"
      }]
    }],
    childNodes: [{
      name: "C",
      childProps: [{
        prop_list: [{
          name: "CS1"
        }, {
          name: "CS2"
        }]
      }],
    }]
  }],
  childProps: [{
    prop_list: [{
      name: "AS1"
    }, {
      name: "AS2"
    }]
  }]
}

function printPaths(node, path) {
  
  const nodeName = node.name ? (path ? ',' : '') + node.name : ''
  const nodePath = (path ? path : '') + nodeName  
  const nodeChildren = Object.values(node).filter(Array.isArray).flat()
    
  return nodeChildren.length > 0 ? nodeChildren
  .map(nodeChild => printPaths(nodeChild, nodePath)).flat() : nodePath
}

console.log( printPaths(input) )
```