# Get new array from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that has another array inside.

```
[
    [
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "title": "title 1",
        },
        {
          "userId": 2,
          "title": "title 2",
        }
    ],
    [
        {
          "userId": 3,
          "title": "title 3",
        }
    ]
]
```

I am trying to get a new array with userId only. For e.g.

```
[
  { "userId": 1 },
  { "userId": 2 },
  { "userId": 3 }
]
```

`array.map(o => o.userId)` works for array of objects and don't know how can i get inside array.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: use for loop or prepare data as you want on backend

Comment: [`Array.prototype.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript flattening an array of arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158723/javascript-flattening-an-array-of-arrays-of-objects) and [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025) and [How to flatten nested array in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27266550)

Answer (score 2):

you'll have to [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) the array first :

```js
const data = [
    [
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "title": "title 1",
        },
        {
          "userId": 2,
          "title": "title 2",
        }
    ],
    [
        {
          "userId": 3,
          "title": "title 3",
        }
    ]
]

const result = data.flat().map(({userId}) => ({userId}));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Literally half way through typing this same answer. This is the easiest way to achieve your outcome.

Comment: Same answer. Ahhhh!!! 

Answer (score 2):

You can flatten the array using `array#concat` and then using destructuring and `array#map` generate the array.

```js
const data = [ [ { "userId": 1, "title": "title 1", }, { "userId": 2, "title": "title 2", } ], [ { "userId": 3, "title": "title 3", } ] ],
      result = [].concat(...data).map(({userId}) => ({userId}));
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is fairly new; in case you can't use it you can use a combination of `reduce` and `map`:

```js
const data = [
    [
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "title": "title 1",
        },
        {
          "userId": 2,
          "title": "title 2",
        }
    ],
    [
        {
          "userId": 3,
          "title": "title 3",
        }
    ]
]

const userIds = data.reduce((_, a) => {
 return _.concat(a.map(({ userId }) => ({ userId })))
}, [])

console.log(userIds)
```

A benefit about `map` within the `reduce` call is that you're only iterating over the array once instead of chaining. This will have better performance over larger arrays than chaining array methods.

<sup>*All assuming your data structure is only one level deep!*</sup>

Comment: You're iterating once for the enclosing array and then iterating *each* element with `.map` . If anything I expect that this would be marginally slower because it needs to create a function for each inner element iteration.

Comment: @NikKyriakides not that jsperf is the end-all for the subject, but I decided to [run this through and check `flat` vs this method.](https://jsperf.com/array-flat-vs-reduce/1). At least in this case, reduce is _much_ faster.

Comment: Really? Interesting. Can't check your benchmark now but if you say so.

Comment: Honestly it surprised me, too!

Answer (score 1):

Another one using [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), for browsers [that don't support `Array.flat`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Browser_compatibility)

```js
const data = [
  [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "title": "title 1",
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "title": "title 2",
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "title": "title 3",
    }
  ]
]

const result = data.reduce((arr, i) => {
  return arr.concat(i.map(({ userId }) => ({ userId })))
}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score -1):

Just get everything out in a new array :)

```js
let arr = [
    [
        {
          "userId": 1,
          "title": "title 1",
        },
        {
          "userId": 2,
          "title": "title 2",
        }
    ],
    [
        {
          "userId": 3,
          "title": "title 3",
        }
    ]
]

let newArr = []
arr.forEach(i => i.forEach(o => newArr.push(o)))
console.log(newArr.map(o => o.userId))
```