# Display elements of an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have got an objects of arrays.

The 1,2,3,4,are the title index.

I want to extract each array of objects for each title separately

Here is the object with index and its corresponding values as array of objects

```
Object {
  "1": Array [
    Object {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "107250.13",
      "@TEUR": "מרכיבי שכר לתשלום",
    },
    Object {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "50.00",
      "@TEUR": "שכר יסוד",
    },
    Object {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "13652.67",
      "@TEUR": "ש.רגילות",
    },
  ],
  "2": Array [
    Object {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55",
      "@TEUR": "תשלום קיטנה",
    },
  ],
  "3": Array [
    Object {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "3200.00",
      "@TEUR": "תוספת פינוק",
    },
  ],
  "4": Array [
    Object {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "11250.00",
      "@TEUR": "תוספת ג'רג'ראת",
    },
  ],
}
```

**For example**:-- under first index i.e. **1** ,
i want to display below array of objects and so on like this.

```
Array [
    Object {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "107250.13",
      "@TEUR": "מרכיבי שכר לתשלום",
    },
    Object {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "50.00",
      "@TEUR": "שכר יסוד",
    },
    Object {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "13652.67",
      "@TEUR": "ש.רגילות",
    },
  ],
```

kindly let me know what logic to be implemented on this?

Thanks.

Comment: needs more clarity. please explain properly what do you want to do

Comment: have you tried Object["1"]?

Comment: i extract all title index..@TheKNVB

Comment: Can you add a snippet to your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript flattening an array of arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29158723/javascript-flattening-an-array-of-arrays-of-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  "1": [
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "107250.13",
      "@TEUR": "מרכיבי שכר לתשלום"
    },
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "50.00",
      "@TEUR": "שכר יסוד"
    },
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "13652.67",
      "@TEUR": "ש.רגילות"
    }
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55",
      "@TEUR": "תשלום קיטנה"
    }
  ],
  "3": [
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "3200.00",
      "@TEUR": "תוספת פינוק"
    }
  ],
  "4": [
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "11250.00",
      "@TEUR": "תוספת ג'רג'ראת"
    }
  ]
};
/* store each array in new lists container */
const lists = Object.keys(obj).map((index) => {
  return obj[index];
});
/* iterate on each list */
lists.map((list) => console.log(...list));
```

Lets do in a very simple and straight forward way. Extract all the lists, save that into another variable for later use and then iterate

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```js
//create empty array
let Array = []

//and this is your Object
const Obj = {
  "1": [
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "107250.13",
      "@TEUR": "מרכיבי שכר לתשלום",
    },
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "50.00",
      "@TEUR": "שכר יסוד",
    },
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "13652.67",
      "@TEUR": "ש.רגילות",
    },
  ],
  "2": [
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55",
      "@TEUR": "תשלום קיטנה",
    },
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55",
      "@TEUR": "תשלום קיטנה",
    },
  ],
  "3": [
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "3200.00",
      "@TEUR": "תוספת פינוק",
    },
  ],
  "4": [
    {
      "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "11250.00",
      "@TEUR": "תוספת ג'רג'ראת",
    },
  ],
}

//now just push your Object to your Array
Array.push(Obj)
console.log("Array: ", Array)
//Below is the way you can get specific 1,2,3,4 index objects with the map function
Array.map(obj => console.warn("obj: ", obj[1]));
```

Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

This code will convert the object to Array.

```
const Obj = {
    1: [
        {
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "107250.13",
            "@TEUR": "מרכיבי שכר לתשלום",
        },
        {
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "50.00",
            "@TEUR": "שכר יסוד",
        },
        {
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "13652.67",
            "@TEUR": "ש.רגילות",
        },
    ],
    2: [
        {
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55",
            "@TEUR": "תשלום קיטנה",
        },
        {
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "182.55",
            "@TEUR": "תשלום קיטנה",
        },
    ],
    3: [
        {
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "3200.00",
            "@TEUR": "תוספת פינוק",
        },
    ],
    4: [
        {
            "@SCHUM_HODSHI": "11250.00",
            "@TEUR": "תוספת ג'רג'ראת",
        },
    ],
};

const idx = Object.keys(Obj).map((key) => {
    return parseInt(key) - 1;
});

// this will store the contents of the array you want
const newArray = Array(idx + 1);

for (let index of idx) {
    newArray[index] = Obj[index + 1][0];
}
```